# Migration from a complex C++ application to C# a -- good idea?

Tags: c#, design, c++, migration

We currently have a complex VC++ software application, which uses a library like ObjectARX to build the dll. I feel there are many features in C# like Collections, Generics, and other libraries which can be used to build the current application in a better and efficient way.

I have been thinking about it, but I am not sure on how to present it to my supervisor and colleagues.

I would appreciate any help, to help me think in the right direction and highlight the points to bring it to the team.

Few points that I thought was;

1. With some current examples, implementing it in C# with the features.
2. Highlight the development time is comparatively lesser in C# than C++.
3. Use a Design Architecture.

Comment: Make sure you read and understand http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html before you promise anything.

Comment: "Use a Design pattern, which will help us to maintain the application in a better way." What on earth do you mean by that? Do you think design patterns are things you buy from the store and plug into your application to make them run with fewer bugs, or something?

Comment: "Highlight the development time is comparatively lesser in C# than C++."  That sounds extremely suspect. It's certainly not true if your developers know C++ but don't know C#.

Comment: @djechlin Currently we are a team of 2, and I am maintaining and developing the application with my supervisor. I am a Jr. Developer and am interested in learning and developing more. I was curious to have an idea with the same. This will be a great opportunity for me, if I go that direction, so just thought of sharing with you guys and know, what do you'll think of the same. I did get some beautiful answers from Lauren and gnat below. Thanks for all the help and comments.

Comment: Is the system working fine, stable?  Rewriting just for the sake of rewriting is a big no-no that often spells disaster.

Comment: @MetalMikester The system is working fine. I believe I got the answer I was looking for, I plan to implement the system in C# in my odd times,(weekends and after work hours) so that I can have an experience in Software Development and slowly if it looks beeter I can present it to my Supervisor too. Should that be good?

Comment: Hey, it's your time. ;)  Worst case scenario, you gain some experience in a different language and environment.

Comment: Thank You @MetalMikester for the encouragement. It helps a lot. :)

Comment: @MetalMikester worst case, you go bankrupt or lose your job, lose your market share, and you gain some experience in a different language and environment.

Comment: The way I see it. There's no worst case when you are trying. You will always have things to gain. Most importantly EXPERIENCE

Comment: Moving to C# would be a downgrade for generics support.

Comment: @djechlin He said he'd work on it on weekends and after hours and then see what comes out.  The C++ system lives on either way, unless he does a fantastic job and they decide to go ahead with that.

Comment: OP is upset about dependency on massive third party libraries and API changes and feels like a victim of a platform? Answer: move to an even bigger, more complex and bloated platform, where they might still be at AutoCAD and Microsoft's mercy. Win?

Comment: The C++ standard library has templates (a more powerful form of generics) and collection types. So these should not count as an advantage of C#.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Short answer

You should consider that it's a very risky and costly idea that may not give you as many benefits as you think it might.

## Long answer

You should consider the following:

C++ is a language that can be used at a very high level, that is cross platform (though that depends on how much you used the VC proprietary extensions) and for which many very mature tools exist. C++11 will add even more juicy bit to handle annoying use cases.

If you're thinking about a full rewrite, don't forget that rewriting *fully debugged code* is time you won't be implementing any new features. If you don't have a clear benefit for using C#, this is throwing money and time through the window.

If the team knows C++, then for a long time writing code in C# will be slower despite any advantage that C# brings.

You have two option for migrating your apps : restart from scratch (and see http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html , already posted), or add new features by maintaining a mapping layer between the C++ and C# code. While C# is quite good as far as calling native code go, it's still some pretty complex code to write. If you either use P/Invoke or C++/CLI, both will force you to know much deeper detail about the platform than would be required for a pure C# solution. Also, you'll spend an awful lot of time marshalling data between managed and native code. A better option may be COM, though I hope you like ATL programming.

The biggest benefits of C# are its simplicity and garbage collector that free you from thinking about a lot of corner cases. That mean it can be developed by developers that are less hardcore than what you need for C++. In your case, your team already know C++ so those benefit are much less present. If you use unique_ptr, shared_ptr, RAII and such, much of the dangerous part of C++ can be managed. Yes, you have more options to shoot yourself in the foot, but you avoid the dangerous parts.

## But still...

If you're not talking about a full rewrite, yes, it could be possible to develop *some* part of the application in C#. But *always* keep it mind the cost of the mapping layer between C++ and C#. I would recommend exporting your C# parts as COM modules and calling that from C++. Be sure it bring a real advantage. If you must constantly convert `vector<>` to `IList<>` and must constantly convert your C++ type to C# one, any speed advantage of C# will be lost. You gain most of converting to C# and .NET when *everything* can stay inside the CLR. Getting everything inside the CLR mean a complete rewrite of a complex application and that is dangerous proposition.

All in all, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Sounds like C++11 might be a better choice. You'll get some of the benefits of C# development, without the migration drawbacks.

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like your'e about to make a lot of really bad decisions.

> Highlight the development time is comparatively lesser in C# than C++.

That sounds *incredibly* suspect. It's certainly not true if your team knows C++ but doesn't know C#, for instance.

> I feel there are many features in C# like Collections, Generics, and other libraries which can be used to build the current application in a better and efficient way.

C++ definitely has those things and in fact generics are more facile in C++ than any other language. It sounds like you just heard somewhere that C# is better, so want to spend weeks rewriting everything into C#, then not actually be any better at doing things in C# than you are in C++. Start with STL and boost...

> Use a Design pattern, which will help us to maintain the application in a better way.

You seem to have no idea what a design pattern is.

Long story short: You cannot make a sound engineering case based on hearsay. You must make it on technical knowledge.

Comment: RAII is quite doable in C# as well -- see [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Comment: @ikh: `IDisposable` is mostly for unmanaged resources; for managed objects, it does not guarantee that those objects get garbage collected immediately, only that they are marked for garbage collection when the class instance is disposed, which happens anyway when the object goes out of scope.  The only way to simulate RIAA with a managed object is to *force* a garbage collection to occur, which is not really the same thing.

Comment: @Robert Yes, but the cases where RAII is really valuable are those which the syntactic pattern associated with IDisposable addresses. The rest is about the difference between different styles of memory management (direct vs. GC).

Comment: Really appreciate your comments, it definitely gives me a very good idea of the same.

Comment: @ikh you don't understand what RAII is. Its not the ability to create a 'cleanup' method (any old fool can do that). The power in RAII is that the cleanup is called automatically for you. The closest thing to RAII in C# is the using statement, but then as you have to litter your code with that, and its not always exception safe, its not really much of a substitute.

Comment: @gbjbaanb `using` was exactly what I meant.  It works, and it's perfectly correct to view it as RAII implementation, even if it's a bit more verbose than C++.  In any case, the point is that it's a mistake to say that RAII is unique to C++, esp when comparing it to C#.

Comment: @everyone removed that line, that clearly wasn't the point.

Comment: @ikh. using-blocks use scoping like RAII but there is more to RAII than scoping. Real RAII is implicit. Using-blocks are explicit. In c# you must explicitly write a block, which is a syntax alternative of explicitly writing try/finally-dipose(). Real RAII would not require to you write anything, it just happens. You could say C# has an explicit version of RAII, but it is not possible for C# (and many other languages) to support implicit RAII.

Answer (score 9):

> We currently have a complex VC++ software application, which uses a
>   library like ObjectARX to build the dll. I feel there are many
>   features in C# like Collections, Generics, and other libraries which
>   can be used to build the current application in a better and efficient
>   way.

<sub>(Remark. ObjectARX is the extension API for AutoCAD. Thus, OP is asking about a domain-specific application known to require deep domain-specialized knowledge.)</sub>

Take a deep breath and ask yourself whether the complexity of the software comes from the domain (computer-aided design and computational geometry), or from the choice of language. If the complexity comes from the domain, changing language may not significantly make your job easier.

Case in point, using a dumb example: a `Polygon` is not the same as `IList<Point2>`. How would an `IList` know how to check for repeated points? Self-intersecting segments? Embedding a coplanar 2D polygon into a plane in the 3D space?

Occasionally, the lack of some syntactic sugar in some languages will indeed complicate domain-specific software development. A prime example is lambda function. With C++11, these *essential* syntactic sugar can be used to simplify and modernize the code. If this is the case, modernizing the C++ code may be a better choice than migrating to C#.

<sub>Another remark to other readers: Each release of ObjectARX for Visual Studio is tied to a specific version of Visual Studio, and is neither backward nor forward compatible. As of ObjectARX 2013, use of VS2010 SP1 is required. (Thus, OP cannot easily recommend using VS2012 unless the vendor release a new version of ObjectARX and the customer (OP's employer) upgrades to it.) http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?id=12257036&siteID=123112</sub>

<sub>Fortunately, VS2010 SP1 also supports a useful subset (but not all) of the C++11 syntax. In particular the iterator for-loop would simplify newly-written code somewhat. The benefit, however, might not justify modifying old code, though.</sub>

---

> I have been thinking about it, but I am not sure on how to present it
>   to my Supervisor and colleagues.

The best way is to just informally ask your supervisor (ideally the software architect) for consideration. It is his/her job to keep an eye on every possibility, including platform choices, migrations and the long-term viability of the project.

<sub>If you actually find yourself more knowledgeable than your supervisor / software architect (which is highly unlikely), find another job.</sub>

---

> I would appreciate any help, to help me think in the right direction
>   and highlight the points to bring it to the team.

My suggestion:

> ***Roman wasn't built in a day.***

At any point in time in your hypothetical re-implementation, the application as a whole needs to be demonstratable (at least runnable and testable). Thus, it will contain parts written in VC++ and parts written in C#. If you can demonstrate that the application still works in a satisfactory way (no major bugs, issues or inefficiency), you have found a "jungle path" from the project's C++ present to the C# future.

A sample worksheet:

- Suppose 5% of the project will be migrated to C#.

  - Which modules or components in the project would you choose to be migrated to C#?
  - How do they interoperate with the rest of the application?
  - Do you foresee any difficulties?
- Repeat the question for 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, and 99%.

Another important question to ask:

- Are there other teams in the company (or paying customers) that depend on the application being C++? Will these teams agree to migrate to C# as well, or will your team be able to provide interoperability for that team?

If you have done this, present your findings to the software architect, who will then be responsible for identifying roadblocks ahead in the remaining sections of this jungle path.

If you don't know how C++ and C# can interoperate ... <sub>I suggest you close this question ASAP before a torrent of downvotes burn away your hard-earned reputation points ...</sub>

Comment: I liked your points, especially, If you actually find yourself more knowledgeable than your supervisor / software architect (which is highly unlikely), find another job. Well, currently I am a Developer with one year of professional experience of Software Development, so was curious to discuss the point in SE. One thing I can assure you, is this question has helped me think and consider lot of things, because of the useful comments shared, so I do not consider to close this question, as I am sure it might be helpful for other Jr.Developers too. Thanks for all the help and comments :)

Answer (score 5):

I have done some applications in C++ and some in C#.

Granted, C++ can be more complex than C# and C# has LINQ, garbage collection etc.
However, features like Collections and Generics are also available in C++, please have a look at STL, Boost and C++11.

"Modernizing" your C++ code seems the better choice for me, e.g.

- using containers like std::list and std::vector instead of C-arrays
- avoiding normal pointers whenever possible and switching to std::shared_ptr etc.
- using std::string instead of char*
- Boost provides a library for nearly everything
- etc.

You should avoid using both C++ and C# in your application (CLR or P/Invoke), unless it's absolutely necessary, e.g. DLL for a device is written in C++ and application has been done in C#. The mapping layer will cause you headaches.

Comment: Regarding the mapping/interop layer: while Microsoft itself had suggested that it is not necessary to adopt a COM-like approach (with its touted P/Invoke), I personally find that a COM-like interface approach is necessary, in order to meet the object lifetime and ownership requirements of both C++ and C#. In this regard, P/Invoke was ineffective in solving the interop problem in an object-oriented application.

Answer (score 2):

99 times out of 100, it's better to refactor code than to rewrite it from scratch.

As for reimplementing into another language: make damn **SURE** that the benefits outweigh the costs and risks, both short term and long term. FYI: as the application's size and/or complexity goes up, the chances that this decision makes sense goes down.